problems with clockwork
i have started a boiler plate project using (npx create-solana-dapp@latest) and i have imported a custom program that uses clockwork sdk . the errors shows that anchor depends on toml v0.8.0 through cargo_toml v0.19.0 while clockwork-sdk v2.0.19 requires toml_datetime v0.6.1 exactly. does anyone have a fix ? im very green when it comes to development in general so forgive the skill issues.

Clockwork shut down a while back and there will be a crate mismatch if you use the latest anchor and Solana versions.
Try updating to the suggested version
cargo update -p toml_edit@0.19.0 --precise 0.6.1

Otherwise, try to update all the dependencies to their latest versions.
edit: the alternative I'd mentioned is Sablier https://github.com/AdrenaFoundation/sablier

thankyou i appreciate your help. is there any other ways you would suggest that i implement the time in the program. so i can have time based rounds in the program without clockwork ?

Let me ask around, I remember there was an alternative to clockwork but I've forgotten the name.
